# Can I use "disagree" and "agree" interchangeably (or rather "agree that" and "disagree that")

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I use "agree" and "disagree" interchangeably? For instance, (utterly disregarding the way the sentence is constructed; it is intentionally written as such) take:

> I agree that our game needs better security measures.

and if I do not believe we require better security measures

> I disagree that our game needs better security measures.

I feel as though "agree" and "disagree" can be used in place of each other, but only when "agree" does not precede "that", and if it does not make it sound ambiguous (like "I disagree our game needs (..)" could be "I disagree, our game needs (..)").

nah cuz fr that sounds odd to me (odd to me as in it looks awkward, not normal) no cap but on god I've seen people use it like that but like want to confirm whether that's proper usage of "disagree", and particularly, if one should prefer to reword their sentence to avoid using it like that.
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't understand _nah cuz fr_ or _no cap but on god_. In answer to your question, I think _I don't agree_ would be more idiomatic in this context.

Comment: While the answers are correct in terms of more frequent usage. I've both heard and used the phraseology of "I disagree that..." The simple answer to your question is "yes, they're interchangeable." However, in my part of the world, we'd say something like "I disagree. I think our game..." more frequently.

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much JBH and Kate Bunting. @KateBunting, "cuz fr" means "because, for real", "no cap" is used to mean "in all seriousness" and "on god" means "I swear". Why I felt like using those terms I cannot answer, but there's what that means.

Comment: Well, can I suggest that you use standard English when posting on this forum in future?

Comment: A fine suggestion. What I used were either common abbreviations or informal expressions, though (granted, maybe not very befitting where only formal English is rife).  I'll either take your advice or place these strategically such that they do not impact the clarity of my writing. Thank you, Kate Bunting.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @KateBunting, ***I don't agree** would be more idiomatic in this context.*

Intransitive ***I disagree*** is a perfectly natural two-word assertion, but if there's going to be an associated ***that-*** clause, we normally switch to negated do-support for the base verb...

[image]